Ventana Modal con Bootstrap con Header, Body y Footer. Agregar tabla extendida en el Body
Buen día. Quiero diseñar una ventana Modal que muestre

Un Header con título.

Un Body que contenga un control de búsqueda (TextBox y Button arriba y Tabla abajo).

Un Footer con dos Button (Cerrar y Seleccionar)


La vista es algo así.

PROBLEMA: Necesito que que la Tabla ocupe todo el espacio disponible en el Body después de los controles TextBox y el Button Buscar. Además, quisiera que el Scroll sólo aparezca cuando la lista sobrepasa la altura disponible en la tabla.
Éste es el código que tengo hasta ahora.
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<style>

    .modal-tall .modal-dialog {
        height: 60%;
    }

    .modal-content {
        height: 60%;
    }

    .row-selected {
        background-color: lightgreen;
    }

    #TblSearchResults thead, #TblSearchResults thead tr th {
        position: sticky;
        top: 0;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    #TblSearchResults thead {
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px lightgray;
    }

    #DivSearchTable {
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }

</style>

<button data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#Search" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary ms-1" data-bs-SesrchType="Empleados">Buscar</button>

<div id="Search" class="modal modal-tall fade" tabindex="0">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
    <div class="modal-content border border-secondary">
      <div class="modal-header bg-secondary bg-gradient bg-opacity-50">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="tituloModal">Buscar</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="d-flex">
            <input type="text" id="TxtSearchTerm" name="TxtSearchTerm" placeholder="Escriba para realizar la búsqueda" style="width: 100%" />
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary ms-1" onclick="FnPerformSearch('Empleados')">Buscar</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="DivSearchTable" class="row mt-2">
          <table id="TblSearchResults" class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
              <tr class="table-header">
                <th scope="col" width="18%">
                  Value
                </th>
                <th scope="col" width="18%">
                  Code
                </th>
                <th scope="col" width="84%">
                  Text
                </th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="TblBodySearch">
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Seleccionar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

Espero haberme dado a entender... Muchas gracias por el apoyo.

Gabo77, dado que un par de veces revertiste ediciones: recuerda evitar las firmas, taglines o saludos; además, explica tanto el comportamiento deseado (que ya lo hiciste), como el comportamiento actual. Las ediciones son para mejorar tu pregunta y para que sean más legibles.
